# Asp.netCore Hangfire Configurations?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, hangfire

I am running MongoDb via docker and running Asp Net project with docker. But I don't get any error while working with WebAPI. I get the following error when working with Docker.

Hangfire Config;

```
builder.Services.AddHangfire(configuration => configuration
            .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
            .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
            .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
            .UseMongoStorage(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MongoDatabaseConnectionString"), new MongoStorageOptions
            {
                //ConnectionCheckTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                //InvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                //QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                MigrationOptions = new MongoMigrationOptions
                {
                    MigrationStrategy = new MigrateMongoMigrationStrategy(),
                    BackupStrategy = new CollectionMongoBackupStrategy()
                },

            }));
    builder.Services.AddHangfireServer();
```

```
 "MongoDatabaseConnectionString": "mongodb://localhost:27019/Movelland-marketing-test-db",
```

```
 "HangfireSettings": {
    "Username": "admin",
    "Password": "1234"
  },
```

Hangfire Options;

```
var hangFireOptions = new DashboardOptions
        {
            AppPath = "/swagger",
            DashboardTitle = "Hangfire Özet",
            Authorization = new IDashboardAuthorizationFilter []
            {
                new BasicAuthAuthorizationFilter(
                    new BasicAuthAuthorizationFilterOptions
                    {
                        RequireSsl = false,
                        SslRedirect = false,
                        LoginCaseSensitive = false,
                        Users = new BasicAuthAuthorizationUser[]
                        {
                            new BasicAuthAuthorizationUser
                            {
                                Login = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("HangfireSettings:Username"),
                                PasswordClear = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("HangfireSettings:Password")
                            }
                        }
                    })
            }

app.UseHangfireDashboard("/Hangfire", hangFireOptions);
```

Error Code;

```
Hangfire.Mongo.MongoConnectException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=
Did not receive ping response from 'Movelland-marketing-test-db' within 5000ms
assuming not able to connect to 'mongodb://<username>:<password>@localhost:27019'
you can disable database ping via the MongoStorageOption 'CheckConnection' field

  Source=Hangfire.Mongo
  StackTrace:
   at Hangfire.Mongo.MongoStorage.CheckConnection()
   at Hangfire.Mongo.MongoStorage..ctor(IMongoClient mongoClient, String databaseName, MongoStorageOptions storageOptions)
   at Hangfire.Mongo.MongoBootstrapperConfigurationExtensions.UseMongoStorage(IGlobalConfiguration configuration, String connectionString, MongoStorageOptions storageOptions)
   at Movelland.Marketplace.Api.Program.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Main>b__4(IGlobalConfiguration configuration) in C:\Users\pc1\Source\Repos\emreturedamasko\Movelland.ECommerce\Movelland.Marketplace.API\Program.cs:line 149
   at Hangfire.HangfireServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<AddHangfire>b__10(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Hangfire.HangfireServiceCollectionExtensions.ThrowIfNotConfigured(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Hangfire.HangfireApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseHangfireDashboard(IApplicationBuilder app, String pathMatch, DashboardOptions options, JobStorage storage)
   at Movelland.Marketplace.Api.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\pc1\Source\Repos\emreturedamasko\Movelland.ECommerce\Movelland.Marketplace.API\Program.cs:line 351

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
```

[Docker Container Mongo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gN6k.png)

How do I get Hangfire MongoDb access?

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wzrqw.png)

[Hangfire Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZVR5.png)

[Hangfire conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPkgW.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please try to share errors, logs, config and code always as TEXT not as image. It is much better to read and help.

Comment: I made an edit, waiting for your help.

Comment: Is your hangfire running on mongodb server? Connection string suggests its localhost... check ports to validate